# Как отфильтровать значения объекта по значениям из массива?

Tags: javascript

Есть входной массив вида

```
  const array1 = [
    { category: "video", field: "flg", value: 97 },
    { category: "deposit", field: "income_sum1", value: 72 },
    { category: "deposit", field: "income_sum2", value: 72 }
  ];
```

Есть входной объект вида

```
const object = {
  video: {
    flg: 1
  },
  deposit: {
    income_sum1: "3545",
    income_sum2: "4.88",
    income_sum3: "17.06",
    income_rating: 60
  },
  property2: {
    sum: 47999
  }
};
```

Нужно получить результирующий объект вида:

В этом объекте остались только ключи, которых нет в массиве array1 и значения также

```
   const result = {
      deposit: {
        income_sum2: "4.88",
        income_sum3: "17.06",
        income_rating: 60
      },
       property2: {
    sum: 47999
  }
    };
```

Comment: У массивов нет ключей.

Comment: я понимаю. мне нужно получить объект result на основе объекта и массива

Comment: почему именно такой результат? почему убрался video.flg, и deposit.income_sum1 но  не убрался deposit.income_sum2?